# How to fill different values in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot

I used pivot_table group a dataframe named df,

```
UserId  eventA  eventB  eventC  ...   date           days  
  1      77       4       9         2015-11-01         2
  1       3       1       1         2015-12-30        60
  1      37       1       2         2016-04-23       174
  1       6       2       2         2016-06-12       225
  2      42       6       7         2015-09-07       130
 ...     ...     ...     ...       ...
```

drop `date` then

df = df.pivot_table(df, index='UserID',columns='days',fill_value='0')

```
    eventA                          \
 day     1   2   3   4   5   6   7     
UserID                                                                           
 1       0  77   0   0   0   0   0   
 2       0   6   0   0   0   0   9   
 3       0   0   0   0  12   0   0   
 4       0   0   0   0   0   0   3   
 5       0   0   0  33   0   0   0   


... eventG      \
days 8   9   10  ...        769 770   
msno                  ...                  
1    0   12 113 ...         0   0   
2    0   0   0 ...          0   0   
3    0   0  32 ...         66   0   
4    0   0   0 ...          0   0   
5    0   0   0 ...          0  43
```

On another hand I have another dataframe with UsersID, start and end date.
Each user may have multiple records.

I convert `days` from [`date`-first `Start_date`] for each user.

```
   UserID           Start_date                 End_date     
    1               2015-10-31                2015-12-21             
    1               2016-01-01                2016-07-21           
    2               2015-05-01                2016-10-01            
    3               2015-05-22                2015-08-22       
    3               2015-09-09                2015-11-01  
    3               2016-03-31                2016-07-24       
    4               2016-10-31                2016-12-21
```

So the problem is here, I want to find every range time for each user which he is not in the range of (`Start_date`,`End_date`) in days as None and padding them in df.

For example, userID 3 has three ranges and I wish to make `[2015-08-22 to 2015-05-22,2015-09-09 to 2015-05-22]` --at the 30th day to the 111th day, `[2015-11-01 to 2015-05-22,2016-03-31 to 2015-05-22]`--at the 164th day to the 314th day,`[2016-07-24 to 2015-05-22,\ ]`the 429th day to the 770th day--as None.

The final dataframe should be similar like this,

```
   eventA                          \
 day     1   2   3   4   5   6   7     
UserID                                                                           
 1       0  77   0   0   0   0   0   
 2       0   6   0   0   0   0   9   
 3       0   0   0   0  12   0   0   
 4       0   0   0   0   0   0   3   
 5       0   0   0  33   0   0   0   


  ... eventG      \
days 8     9      10    ...    112   113   114...    769  770   
msno                    ...                   ...   
1    0     12    113    ...     0     2     4       None None  
2    0     0       0   ...     12     0     3       None None   
3    0     0      32    ...    None None  None       66    0   
4    0     0       0    ...    5      1     0       None None   
5    0     0       0    ...    None None    2         0   43
```

Hope I made this question clear. 
Looking for someone could help me!

Comment: unclear what you need

Comment: hi@Wen, I use pivot_table to fill value '0' in 'days', but I tried to get the dataframe closer to the real situation. So I try to fill None in them depends on every user if 'days' are not in every range of Start and End date. Some users have multiple Start and End dates.